# Q: Template class that takes either a normal type or a template template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, constexpr

Recently I designed meta-types and the possible operations that would allow compile-time type concatenations:

```
#include <tuple>

template<template<typename...> typename T>
struct MetaTypeTag
{};

/*variable template helper*/
template<template<typename...> typename T>
constexpr MetaTypeTag<T> meta_type_tag = {};

template<typename T>
struct TypeTag
{};

/*comparison*/
template<typename T>
constexpr bool operator==(TypeTag<T>, TypeTag<T>) { return true; }
template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool operator==(TypeTag<T>, TypeTag<U>) { return false; }

/*variable template helper*/
template<typename T>
constexpr TypeTag<T> type_tag = {};

template<template<typename...> typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr TypeTag<T<Ts...>> combine(MetaTypeTag<T>, TypeTag<Ts>...)
{
    return {};
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto combined_tag = combine(meta_type_tag<std::tuple>, type_tag<int>, type_tag<float>);
    static_assert(combined_tag == type_tag<std::tuple<int, float>>, "");
}
```

The `std::tuple` without template arguments cannot be used as a type, but may still appear in the template template parameter.

Now if we try to go one step further, the question is whether there is any way to unify `struct MetaTypeTag` and `struct TypeTag`, since they are both empty classes with one template parameter, or at least it could be possible to use the same variable template `type_tag` but redirect to a different class depending on the type category? So I would imagine something like this:

```
template<???>
constexpr auto type_tag = ????{};

//use with 'incomplete type'
type_tag<std::tuple> //MetaTypeTag<std::tuple>
//use with regular type
type_tag<int> //TypeTag<int>
```

I tried all possible ways - redefinition, explicit specialization, partial specialization, optional template parameters, conditional using alias, but none worked. I had hoped C++17's `template<auto>` would help, but it turns out that one is for non-type only.

Comment: When you say "unify" the MetaTypeTag and TypeTag, what exactly do you mean? Could you give an example of what you expect to achieve please?

Comment: Edited. I mean that either by using the same template class, or the same expression to obtain different behaviors. At start I thought this can be solved with specialization, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the question is whether there is any way to unify `struct MetaTypeTag` and `struct TypeTag`, since they are both empty classes with one template parameter

I don't thinks so.
The best I can imagine to simplify a little (very a little) your code is define a couple of overloaded `constexpr` function, say `getTag()`

```
template <typename T>
auto constexpr getTag ()
 { return TypeTag<T>{}; }

template <template <typename ...> typename T>
auto constexpr getTag ()
 { return MetaTypeTag<T>{}; }
```

so you can call `getTag<T>()` where `T` is either a type or a template.

So you can call `combine()` as follows

```
constexpr auto combined_tag
   = combine(getTag<std::tuple>(), getTag<int>(), getTag<float>());
```

But I don't think is a great improvement.